# SSIS package DataFlowTask for Excel Import to SQL Server 2014 runs on my local instance, but when deployed fails on the server

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have an SSIS package that imports data from a very simple Excel 2010 (`.xlsx`) file to SQL Server. I can get the package to run on my local and can execute the package from my local to the server. However, when I deploy the package to the server it fails with

> DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER
>   The Microsoft  Access engine cannot open or write to the file \server\database\filename' (for security reasons I cannot share the actual unc). It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data'.

I have been chasing this for about 3 weeks now.  Forcing the 32-bit runtime in the SSIS package and on the SQL Server Agent level does not correct the issue. I have also uninstalled the AccessDatabaseEngine (32 and 64 bit) from the server and reinstalled using the install exe that I used to configure my local. To no avail. I also know for fact that the Excel file is not open or being accessed by another user/connection.

I get a successful connection to the server, but not to the Excel file. I also need to mention the package was developed in VS2013 and the server it needs to run on is SQL Server 2014 (Build 12.0.5000.0). My local is build 12.0.4468.0. Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated. My team is stumped.

Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly says you do not have the necessary permissions.

Please check with your admin try it again.

You can use the deployment wizard to deploy your SSIS package.

Regards
Safi